# implementeed the jquery filer on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-filer, jquery-filer

I was implemented the [jQuery filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/) on bootstrap modal.

Now, when first time modal user opens the modal and upload the images everything goes good but if user close the modal and now upload the image then the images are not uploaded. looking as we have to reset the filer before open the modal.

Any help will be helpful.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `close the modal and now upload the image` how the user can upload an image? The uploader container is in the modal isn't?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the filer on $.ready of the modal:

```js
     $('#filer_input').filer(function(default_options){
         var Obj = {
           showThumbs: true,
                 addMore: true,
                 clipBoardPaste:true,
                 captions:{
                     button: "Seleziona file",
                     feedback: "Seleziona files da caricare",
                     feedback2: "File selezionati",
                     drop: "Porta qui i file",
                     removeConfirmation: "Vuoi rimuovere questo file?",
                     errors: {
                         filesLimit: "Solo {{fi-limit}} file per ogni upload.",
                         filesType: "Sono consentite solo immagini.",
                         filesSize: "{{fi-name}} risulta troppo grande! Max size {{fi-fileMaxSize}} MB.",
                         filesSizeAll: "Files troppo grandi! Max size {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
                         folderUpload: "Non puoi caricare cartelle.    "
                     }
                 }
         };
      return Obj;
     });
```